# Write to file does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, writetofile

When i try to write to file with this code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"default" ofType:@"txt"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString*s = @"some text";
BOOL successful = [s writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",error);
NSLog(@"%d",successful);
```

Nothing happens. NSLog says:

```
(null)
1
```

Comment: That sounds like there was no error and it was successful. What does "nothing happens" mean?

Comment: @iOSGuru248 I can't be certain but it sounds an awful lot like he was expecting the "some text" string to be written to the path he specified or an error if it wasn't successful. I think this should be filed as a bug with Apple, given the main bundle isn't writable but no "access denied" error occurred. The system is apparently lying.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're writing over the main bundle try this:

```
    NSString *applicationDocumentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *storePath = [applicationDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"default.txt"];
```

Here we're trying to write over our app Documents directory. Because you can't write on the main bundle

Comment: Thanks, now it works, but how to create a folder in Documents directory?